# Using proc datasets copy on files that fit a certain condition

Tags: copy, proc

As the title suggests I'd like to copy SAS tables from a Library to another but not all tables. I'd like to copy the tables which names start with 's' for example.
I know that I have to use proc  datasets copy but which option? How ? 
(English isn't my first English so Im sorry if my question isnt clear))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easier to just use `PROC COPY`.  You can use `:` as a wildcard in the `SELECT` statement.

```
12220  proc copy inlib=work outlib=out;
12221    select c: / mtype=data ;
12222  run;

NOTE: Copying WORK.CHECK to OUT.CHECK (memtype=DATA).
NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set WORK.CHECK.
NOTE: The data set OUT.CHECK has 3 observations and 4 variables.
NOTE: Copying WORK.CLASS to OUT.CLASS (memtype=DATA).
NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set WORK.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set OUT.CLASS has 19 observations and 5 variables.
```

Comment: where would the 's' fit here? (As in table name starts with 's')

Comment: Replace the `c:` with `s:` in the `select` statement.